# Strange things about numpy indexing using empty ndarray

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, indexing

When I do numpy indexing, sometimes the index can be an empty list, in that way I want numpy to also return a empty array. For example:

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3])

b = []

print a[b]
```

This works perfectly fine! when the result gives me:

```
result:[]
```

But when I use ndarray as indexer, strange things happened:

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3])

b = []

c = np.array(b)

print a[c]
```

This gives me an error:

```
IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type
```

However, When I do this:

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3])

b = []

d = np.arange(0, a.size)[b]

print a[d]
```

Then it works perfectly again:

```
result:[]
```

But when I check the type of c and d, they returns the same! Even the shape and everything:

```
print type(c), c.shape

print type(d), d.shape

result：<type 'numpy.ndarray'> (0L,)

result：<type 'numpy.ndarray'> (0L,)
```

So I was wondering if there is anything wrong with it? How come a[c] doesn't work but a[d] works? Can you explain it for me? Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

There is a simple resolution `numpy` arrays have in a sense two types. their own type which is `numpy.ndarray` and the type of their elements which is specified by a `numpy.dtype`. Arrays used for indexing must have elements of integer or boolean `dtype`. In your examples you use two array creation methods with different default `dtypes`. The `array` factory which defaults to a float `dtype` if nothing else can be inferred from the template. And `arange` which uses an integer `dtype` unless you pass some float parameters.
Since the `dtype` is also a property of the array it is specified and checked even if there are no elements. Empty lists are not checked for `dtype` because they do not have a `dtype` attribute.

Answer (score 3):

numpy doesn't know what type the empty array is.

Try:

```
c = np.array(b, dtype=int)
```

Comment: Thanks this works! But I still think this is a little inconvenient. How come I have to tell numpy the type of an empty array. If this is a list I wouldn't have to worry about it.

Comment: It may be inconvenient for *you* in this context, but not necessarily for others.  Most people don't need to make empty arrays as you did.  The more common way of making a blank/empty array is `np.zeros(n)`.  That too is dtype float.